# Export TeeChart as Image on Xamarin Android without Showing

Tags: android, image, xamarin, export, teechart

I am trying to export TeeChart as Image on Xamarin Android without showing the chart. It creates the file on external storage. However, the file is broken and cannot be loaded.

Do you know if it is possible? If it possible, can you give me a sample code doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the view's bitmap and storage it:

```
Steema.TeeChart.TChart tChart1= new Steema.TeeChart.TChart(this);
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar bar1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar();
tChart1.Series.Add(bar1);
bar1.Add(3, "Pears", System.Drawing.Color.Red);
bar1.Add(4, "Apples", System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
bar1.Add(2, "Oranges", System.Drawing.Color.Green);
Steema.TeeChart.Themes.BlackIsBackTheme theme = new Steema.TeeChart.Themes.BlackIsBackTheme(tChart1.Chart);
theme.Apply();
// here you can get the view' bitmap
tChart1.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
tChart1.BuildDrawingCache();
Bitmap viewBitmap = tChart1.DrawingCache;
//storage the bitmap.
FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(FilesDir.AbsolutePath + "111111.jpg");
viewBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 90, stream);
```

[Here is the `setDrawingCacheEnabled` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled(boolean)), which allow you get view's bitmap.